# Creating a parasitic Windows installation

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, multi-boot, pata

Okay, I have recently revived an old computer of mine, and had an idea I wanted to explore.

It's an old Gigabyte board with Intel Pentium 4 @3.0 GHz Prescott processor.
I also have two IDE hard drives.

So here is the idea:

I want to put Win XP on both of the drives to create a dual boot. Simple enough. The catch? One of them (let's call him the victim) mustn't know the other one (the parasite) exists. Let me explain further.

What are the conditions that have to be met?

First off, when booting up the computer, it must boot to the victim if nothing is done. If a condition is met, it gives you a choice or boots the parasite directly. The condition can be anything - an USB stick plugged in with some data, a CD-drive in the DVD-ROM, a specific button being pressed, anything really. The another problem that comes into play here is the IDE configuration. Due to the cable length, I can have one of two setups:

IDE1Master: HDD1

IDE1Slave: HDD2

IDE2Master: DVDROM

IDE2Slave: None

or

IDE1Master: DVDROM

IDE1Slave: HDD1

IDE2Master: HDD2

IDE2Slave: None

Be as it may, one of the HDD will always be a slave. I know there is a utility called GNU GRUB, a bootloader. I haven't had time to mess with it yet, but if I can make it to show the selection screen for a second (long enough for me to hit down arrow and enter) and then go to default boot if nothing selected, that would solve the first issue. Is it possible?

I think that is it. The point is that unaware user of the computer should happily use the victim without having the slightest idea of existance of another Windows installation. The more advanced the user I can fool, the better.

I think if I can hide parasitic installation when booting I can call it a successful project.

What do you think?

Comment: As you explained it, even if you got it working both drives would show up with their own drive letter, no matter which partition booted.  So how would that be described as "hidden"? As one step though, I might suggest booting off a USB with `grub` on it set to boot the secondary install.  You can then think of that USB drive as a key to trigger the secondary system.

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I needed. I think I can use Computer Managment on the victim to just hide the drive, at least in explorer.

Comment: What I ended up doing is using the first method. I installed secondary Windows on the HDD2 and removed any associations to it on primary Windows. So when normal user boots the computer, it defaults without asking to HDD1 and starts primary windows without any knowledge of secondary install. I put in a disk with a boot manager, go to boot menu, boot from CD and select my windows install. Perhaps it's not perfect, but it works. And the original user doesn't know anything is there, nor it affects it in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should re-evaluate what it is your trying to achieve. Because I can assure you, that the solution does not involve a second "hidden" hard drive.

If your determined to go this route, and I don't see why you would be... I'd look into IDE ribbon cable switches. Make it a physical switch in the back of the desktop case.  Look up IDE cable select, certain ribbons had a dedicated line for this.

Comment: Well this enables me to have one IDE cable with one HDD and another with HDD and DVDROM, but I can switch the master/slave roles and make both HDDs masters...

Comment: How often are you going to be switching between the two machines? Why not just have both hard drives set as master, and then replace them when you need to? If you're wanting to conduct some tom foolery, this is a horrible approach.